# android check if URL contain site name from array always return false

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

I wrote code to check If array Contains url

for example `Sites_array: [youtube.com]`

and the URL like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxx`

```
public boolean check_url(String url){
    sites_array = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sites_array));
    return sites_array.contains(url);
}
```

I call this method like this

```
EditText search_bar = getCustomActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_search_bar);
String site_url = search_bar.getText().toString();

if(check_url(site_url)){
    Log.d("array",">>>>>contain the url");
}else {
    Log.d("array",">>>>>Not contain the url");
}
```

but i got always `false`,any idea how can i fix this.

Comment: Put a breakpoint down at the `return` statement in `check_url`, IMHO `sites_array` will not be filled correctly. Other than that your method should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site url is like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxx` and the array has elements in the form `[youtube.com]` and you are checking whether `[youtube.com]` contains `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxx`, which would always be `false`. You need to do it the other way round, i.e check if the url contains any of the elements in the site array. (`List.contains` checks if the list has that element in it.)

You need to change the `checkUrl` method as below:

```java
public boolean check_url(String url){
    List<String> sites_array = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sites_array));
    for(String site : sites_array){
        if(url.contains(site){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you are using java 8 or above, then you could use streams.

```java
public boolean check_url(String url){
    List<String> sites_array = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sites_array));
    return sites_array.stream()
                      .anyMatch(site -> url.contains(site));
}
```

Inside the `anyMatch` you could also use `url::contains`.

```java
public boolean check_url(String url){
    List<String> sites_array = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sites_array));
    return sites_array.stream()
                      .anyMatch(url::contains);
}
```

Comment: It's not just that he needs to do the check "the other way around", but he calls the `contains` method of the List (Which internally will compare the Strings with equals to check if the passes string is contained in the list), while he needs to iterate/stream over his List and call `contains` on the String elements of the List, not the List itself.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yes. "the other way round" seemed to be a bit confusing, I have updated with what I actually meant

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the domain name first from the URL
then u can check if the array contains it or no
like

```
boolean check_url(String url) throws Exception {
    URL aURL = new URL(url); /* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxx  */
    sites_array = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Sites_array));
    // aURL.getHost() will return    ( youtube.com )
    return sites_array.contains(aURL.getHost()); // true if array contain it 
}
```